# Accordion doesn't automatically count

Tags: count, umbraco, wai-aria, bootstrap-accordion

My accordion doesn't automatically count up, the number stays at 1 for some reason. I am using a CMS called Umbraco on version 7.7.2.

Here's my code:

```
@if(@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("titleAccordeon") != "")
{
  <section class="block block__accordion">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="block__heading col-md-12">
                <h3>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("titleAccordeon")</h3>
                <p>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("introAccordeon")</p>
            </div>
            @if(Model.Content.Accordion != null && Model.Content.Accordion.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Content.Accordion)
                {
                    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    <div class="accordion panel-group col-md-12" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                        <div class="accordion__item">
                            <a class="accordion__item__header" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion-@guid" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-@guid">
                                 @item.Title
                            </a>

                            <div class="collapse" id="accordion-@guid">
                                <div class="accordion__item__body">
                                    @item.Description
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And this is the result on one of the pages:

[image]

All the accordions have a different control-id thanks to the guid. Any idea why it doesn't count up?

Comment: there's nothing in the code here which would produce a number. Is it part of the title? If so then the answer is somewhere in your model logic, not in this view.

Comment: I believe it might have to do with the title. I didn't create the models myself and I'm not able to access them.

Comment: Have you just got them in compiled form, or something? I guess you need to talk to the people who made them then.

Comment: I don't think it's in the title as I just replaced @item.Title with "test". Might be in the Model.Content.Accordion. I'll go through my code, we're trying to get access to the models already, it's just taking a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the code working. I moved one of the div's outside the if code and it worked. Not sure why the div made the accordions count though. Thanks to hardba11 and ADyson for trying to help!

```
 <div class="accordion panel-group col-md-12" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            @if(Model.Content.Accordion != null && Model.Content.Accordion.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Content.Accordion)
                {

                    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

                        <div class="accordion__item">
                            <a class="accordion__item__header" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion-@guid" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-@guid">
                                     @item.Title
                            </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="accordion-@guid">
                                 <div class="accordion__item__body">
                                    @item.Description

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                }
            }
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's some JavaScript which acts on the markup with the accordion classes, perhaps that adds the numbers.

Comment: This sample that I've provided will auto number for you

Answer (score 0):

How is it auto numbering?  I don't see an OL or anything that would auto-number.  Seems like the number is just part of the item.Title?  If that is this case, you could do something like this.

```
@if(Model.Content.Accordion != null && Model.Content.Accordion.Any())
{
    var counter == 1;
    foreach (var item in Model.Content.Accordion)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        <div class="accordion panel-group col-md-12" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="accordion__item">
                <a class="accordion__item__header" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion-@guid" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-@guid">
                         @(counter + ". " + @item.Title)
                </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="accordion-@guid">
                     <div class="accordion__item__body">
                        @item.Description
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It errors at the } before the last one. This makes me believe I am missing a small thing in the code that makes it crash. Thanks for the idea with the counter. Haven't thought about that myself.

Comment: I've managed to get it working now, the 1. is still there and is probably somewhere in a model or defined elsewhere in my code. I'll keep digging. Thanks for the help!